# adobe illustrator to pdf gives strokes around path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export, visual-artifacts

I exported my AI project to pdf and saw some weird white transparent lines between shape

left is from ai right one is from pdf (look closely at hearth shape)

[image]

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate.  If you feel the the duplicate question isn't helpful please make an [edit] going into further detail.

Answer (score 0):

Those may be artefacts created by your `.pdf` viewer. Those are especially common when you view a print-ready `cPDF` on a screen. If you zoom in on the `.pdf` and they are still a single pixel wide or less, then they are artefacts and will not show in print.